# debugging Python with Vscode give syntax error pointing to @@ symbols

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

Have been trying to debug a python script which was made to run by a command:

```
threatingestor config.yml
```

I have added the necessary configuration launch.json for specifying the config file as argument

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "args": ["config.yml"],
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
]}
```

however when debugging I am presented with the below Syntax error which I cannot find away to research it online to correct it. I would really appreciate if you could let me know of any other friendly names/description for the below SyntaxError so i can look it up and understand it. I am aware that the @ symbol is used for decorators in python however I cannot link it to this scenario.

```
...
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/Administrator/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/threatingestor/sources/rss.py", line 12
    @@ -23,7 +30,7 @@ def run(self, saved_state):
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's a diff or something. How did you install ThreatIngestor?

Comment: how does this `rss.py` look like

Comment: what are all these `bin` `lib` `include` `share` directories doing in your project